# Nomenclatura / Naming doubt, using Reports or Log

Tags: names

I'm projecting screens and one of the tabs have the name **"Reports"**, but in this tab the user can see Change Log and 2 Data Viz reports.

Is it right to call it only **"Reports"** or **"Reports and Log"** is more applicable?

Anybody knows if Change Log is a kind of a Report too?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the changelog is to show the changes that have been made on something (like app changes from one version to another). On the other hand a report is more wide and it'ts mostly used to describe what (and even how) something was made or how is it being made.

Since those two are kind of different conecpts, I think it makes sense to use "Reports and Logs" on the tab.

Answer (score 0):

> **Report**
>   *Computers.* output, especially printed, containing organized
>   information.
>   http://www.dictionary.com/browse/report
>
> **Report**
>   *a.* A formal account of the proceedings or transactions of a group: a company's annual report.
>   *b.* A spoken or written account of an event, usually presented in detail: a news report; reports of children getting food poisoning.
>
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/report

Sounds a lot like a change log to me, I can't imagine any issues arising from including it under Reports

Answer (score 0):

It is good to use "Reports" at the entry point. Very common, clear and extensible.

The term is general to everyone and it is also clear, that behind it different types of data could be selected and viewed, but one has to look inside first.

On the reports page you can separate different types of reports arranging them in groups. For ex. in panels with headers. The naming could be by topic (Reports-> |"Tracking" or "History"->"Changes Log"| "Data Viz") or by user consumer role (Reports-> |"Administrator"->"Changes Log"...| "Manager"->...| "Client"->...).

Another good option would be to change the "Reports" tab to a dropdown menu tab with groups and their headers.